# Passing a map object as parameter of the map method of an iterable

Tags: scala, dictionary, implicit-conversion

What I like in Scala is that I often discover new syntaxes just by trying what seems intuitive to me. For example, I have had to decode a text where each character was replaced by a different symbol, so I did as in this simplified example :

```
val map = Map[Char,Char]('h' -> 'd', 'e' -> 'l', 'l' -> 'o', 'w' -> 'r', 'o' -> 'h', 'r' -> 'd', 'd' -> 'e')
println("hello world".split("\\s+").map(word => word.map(map).mkString).mkString(" "))
```

and it works perfectly. I looked in the documentation of `Array.map` to find how it's done (I was exepcting to see some implicit conversion or something like that) but I found nothing. Can someone explain me how is it possible to pass a `Map` as a parameter instead of a function ?

Comment: what's `symbolsMap`?

Comment: @Dima I edited to make it clearer. It's a map that maps every possible character to the corresponding decoded character

Comment: `Map[Char,Char]`, as you can see in the edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In scala, Map actually extends Function1 (via its MapLike parent).  Map[A,B] is actually a Function1[A,B], Similarly, List[A] is a Function1[Int,A], and Set[A] is a Function1[A, Boolean], and of these can act as Functions.

```
scala> val m : Int => String = Map(1 -> "a", 2 -> "b")
m: Int => String = Map(1 -> a, 2 -> b)

scala> m(1)
res0: String = a
```

Comment: That was pretty simple, I should have found by myself ! Thanks anyway to Dima and you

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you look at the [Docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Map), you can see that `Map` actually extends `Function1`, and it's `apply` method is defined intuitively to return the value mapped by the key. So `foo.map(map)` is equivalent to `foo.map(bar => map(bar))`